# How to change the default font size in CLion?

Tags: fonts, clion

Recently I switched from terminal Cpp programming to CLion and found it's a really sweet one.  But the font size is kind of small, so how can I change the default font size of each editor page?  Thanks!

> EDIT: I already know how to change font size **temporarily** by enabling mouse wheel, but it's only works for one editor page only. I am looking for setting that can change the font size in default.

Answer (score 7):

In CLion preference menu, go to `Editor->Colors & Fonts -> Font` (I guessed you might have been here. If not, that's fine),  you would find that the font size blank is frozen.  The reason why it's frozen is that you are using a **READ ONLY** color scheme. To tackle this, simply click button `Save as` and name your own name, then you would have your own scheme, which is a copy of the former one and it is **readable/writable**.  At last, just set the font size you want and apply the setting.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, it perfectly solved my problem, but I don't have enough rep to vote you up. If I earned, I would vote this up ASAP ;-)

Comment: In CLion 2018.1 you need to go to `Preferences->Editor->Color Scheme` and make a copy of scheme there. Then you can go to `Preferences->Editor->Font` and change the font size there.

Comment: In CLion 2018.2 you need to go to `Settings->Editor->Font` (and `Settings` is under the `File` menu).

Answer (score 2):

Besides enabling mouse wheel font zoom, I have also worked out that we can change the font size via shortcut option `increase/decrease font size`, which I customise them to be `Ctrl-Shift-Meta`-`+/-`.  But it still doesn't work permanently, where once I switch a new editor page, the font size is still small.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Mac, go to Preference -- General -- Mouse Control --Change font size with Command + Mouse wheel and apply that. Go to your code and hold the command key with the touch-bar up and down for far and close respectively.